# Quero fazer Play/Pause com imagens como se fosse com hover

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho o código com os botões/imagem funcionais um em cima do outro, mas quero que quando clicar no play a imagem "play" suma e apareça o "pause" e vice-versa.

```
<div class="container">   
            <div class="radio">
                    <audio id="stream" >
                            <source src="songs/y2mate.com - EPIC DUBSTEP DROP FOR REAL MEN.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                    </audio>
                    <img id="play" src="img/play.png" width="80px" onclick="playStream()">
                    <img id="pause" src="img/pause.png" width="80px" onclick="pauseStream()">
           </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script/script.js"></script>"
    
    var stream = document.getElementById('stream');
    var play = document.getElementById('play');
    var pause = document.getElementById('pause');
    
    function playStream(){
            stream.play();
    }
    
    function pauseStream(){
        stream.pause();
    }
```

Comment: ola Bedatty em Editar [ou clique aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/495139/edit) e adicione esse código na pergunta, não use os comentários para isso

Comment: Desculpa, sou novo no fórum e não estava conseguindo colocar o código <html> junto com o de JS, aparecia apenas o de javascript, então tive que optar pela gambiarra kkkkkkk, não farei novamente!

Comment: ah tranquilo, quando precisar fazer isso, tem um botão com tag de código assim `<>`, clicando lá consegue por código que funcione, como na minha resposta

Comment: Certo! Obrigado pelas dicas e pela excelente recepção!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De uma forma bem simples pode fazer assim, escondendo/exibindo ao clicar:

```
function playStream(){
    stream.play();
    document.getElementById('play').style.display == "none";
    document.getElementById('pause').style.display == "block";
}

function pauseStream(){
    stream.pause();
    document.getElementById('play').style.display == "block";
    document.getElementById('pause').style.display == "none";
}
```

Uma outra forma é trabalhar com classes, que fica melhor e também pode iniciar com o pause escondido:

```js
function playStream(){
    stream.play();
    document.getElementById('play').classList.add('hidden');
    document.getElementById('pause').classList.remove('hidden');
}

function pauseStream(){
    stream.pause();
    document.getElementById('play').classList.remove('hidden');
    document.getElementById('pause').classList.add('hidden');
}
```

```css
img {
   width: 80px
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">   
  <div class="radio">
    <audio id="stream" >
          <source src="songs/y2mate.com - EPIC DUBSTEP DROP FOR REAL MEN.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
        <img id="play" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQvZz.png" onclick="playStream()">
        <img id="pause" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgVXL.png" class="hidden" onclick="pauseStream()">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!! Deu certo aqui, eu havia tentado procurar e pesquisar sobre mas estava difícil achar em JS como fazia isso!